# Rails 5 breaks adding text to image via Carrierwave

Tags: carrierwave, image-uploading, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 4 project I'm upgrading to Rails 5.  Image upload breaks when inserting text, when I take out adding the text (`c.draw "text 0,0 'test'"`), it works:

Uploader.rb file:

```
class LeedUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.job.JobNo}/#{model.leed_item.Team}/#{model.id}"
  end

    def fix_exif_rotation #this is my attempted solution
        manipulate! do |img|
          img.tap(&:auto_orient)
        end
    end

    def add_text_medium
        manipulate! do |img|
            img.combine_options do |c|
                    c.background '#000'
              c.gravity 'South'
              c.fill '#00FF3A'
              c.pointsize '24'
              c.draw "text 0,0 'test'"
            end
            img
          end
    end

  version :medium do         
        process :resize_to_limit => [400, 400]
        process :fix_exif_rotation
        process :add_text_medium
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by upgrading ImageMagick from `6.8.7-0` to the latest version: `7.0.4-10` using brew.

Comment: Be aware that brew might not be available on your production server, so you should make sure that you can install the new version of imagemagick on the server before depending on this as a solution.